# Flutter: add image

Tags: flutter

I want to add image before the result. I added in `pubspec.yaml`

- assets/images/ .

Where write Image.asset("assets/images/mark.png")?

Is there any way to do it?

result.dart

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
        class Results extends StatefulWidget {
      final int total, correct, incorrect, notattempted;
      Results({this.incorrect, this.total, this.correct, this.notattempted});
    
      @override
      _ResultsState createState() => _ResultsState();
    }
    
    class _ResultsState extends State<Results> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Container(
              child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                Text("${widget.correct}/ ${widget.total}", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),),
                  SizedBox(height: 5,),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
                    child: Text(
                        "you answered ${widget.correct} answers correctly and ${widget.incorrect} answeres incorrectly",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
    
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 24,),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: (){
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 8),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)
                      ),
                      child: Text("Go to home", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 19),),
                    ),
                  )
              ],),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Is there any way to do it?  In case you want to see the code please let me know I will update more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what do you mean by **image before the result**. Do you mean add the image as first item to be appear under column?

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    class Results extends StatefulWidget {
  final int total, correct, incorrect, notattempted;
  Results({this.incorrect, this.total, this.correct, this.notattempted});

  @override
  _ResultsState createState() => _ResultsState();
}

class _ResultsState extends State<Results> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
            Image.asset('assets/images/mark.png'),
            Text("${widget.correct}/ ${widget.total}", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),),
              SizedBox(height: 5,),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
                child: Text(
                    "you answered ${widget.correct} answers correctly and ${widget.incorrect} answeres incorrectly",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,),

              ),
              SizedBox(height: 24,),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 8),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)
                  ),
                  child: Text("Go to home", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 19),),
                ),
              )
          ],),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

More details about the Asset image can found [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.asset.html).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the Results class with Column widget where you are using. And add image just before in Results class.